# Cordova Custom iOS / Android sounds when app is close or in background

Tags: cordova, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement a custom push notification sound through GCM and APNS using my Cordova/PhoneGap app.

On APNS, I've managed to get the proper beep file name using the PushPlugin. However, I have no idea how to make that sound play when the app is in the background or completely closed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: i have never tried this plugin, but this is maybe the way https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS you just send the push with the sound name on it:

```
{

    "aps" : {

        "alert" : "Your message",

        "badge" : 1,

        "sound" : "yoursound.aiff"

    }

}
```

the sound file with the name yoursound.aiff has to be on the app bundle

Comment: I have a .wav file less than 30 seconds and using Visual Studio with Cordova Tools.. Where to place the sound file and how to access it...

Comment: I don't think you can do that from Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm sending the sound like you described but this also doesn't seem to play using the Media plugin.

Comment: If the sound is in the app bundle and you send the push notification with the name of the sound it just sound when you receive the push, you don't have to use the Media plugin at all.

Comment: I'm using PushPlugin with Cordova/PhoneGap.. does that apply too? I'm guessing since the app is in the background or closed... Will the PushPlugin be able to execute at all?

Comment: No, at least on iOS, the javascript won't be executed when on background, so, no sound from Media plugin, but my approach works, it's how the apple push notifications work

Comment: Wheres the bundle folder in a cordova app? Inside the www folder?

Comment: there is no bundle folder, the bundle is the files that create the app, on xcode you just drag a file to the project and it is added to the app bundle, but I don't think you can do that from visual studio

Comment: So i need to build the solution on xcode... What about the res folder?

Comment: it might work, put the sound there and do a cordova prepare ios

Comment: nop. still can't make this work. I'm sure there's a way to add it to the bundle using VS since it's building using xcode for iOS..

Comment: best thing you can do is contact Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova team and ask if this is possible, maybe they haven't consider it yet